# C# Serialize to JS Object without quoting some values

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net

I am creating a `javascript object` from a `c# object` and one of the properties is a reference to a `js function` , but when serializing the object the value has quotes around it witch makes it a normal string and not a function.
this is the current output :

```
{ "x": "functionNameToBeCalled" }
```

But I need it to be like

```
 { "x": functionNameToBeCalled }
```

Is there anyway to do this with `Json.Net` or do I have to create the js object manually?

I tried using the `JsonPropertyAttribute` but can't figure out which property to set!!!

Comment: Manually create a your own serialization method.

Comment: Since you are using Json.NET this would appear to be a duplicate of [How to serialize a raw json field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15661529/3744182).  Put `[JsonConverter(typeof(PlainJsonStringConverter))]` on the property whose value should be serialized as a raw, unquoted string.

Answer (score 2):

change the way of calling your method, something like this:

```
window.z= function(){ console.log('hi');}
var b = { a: 'z'}
window[b.a]();
```

so no need to change json serialization behavior.

Comment: Yes, because `{ "x": functionNameToBeCalled }` is not valid JSON

Comment: can't change the caller, its a third party component.