# Get JSON.NET in WebAPI to serialize exact type not subclass

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I have three classes in a domain

```
public class ArtistInfo
{
    private Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Artist : ArtistInfo
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedById { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int? TrackNumber { get; set; }
    //[SomeJsonAttribute]
    public ArtistInfo Artist { get; set; }
}
```

From the ASP.NET Web API I return a generic List(of Tracks). No matter what I have tried the Web API returns the Artist property of Track as an Artist not ArtistInfo. Is there someway to limit this in the output of the API to just use ArtistInfo? I don't want to write addition "ViewModels/DTOs" to handle this situation. Can I decorate the ArtistInfo with a hint to the JSON Serializer?

Comment: The used variable name "Artist" is similar to the class name "Artist". are you sure you are not misinterpreting the JSON string ?

Comment: Try setting `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;` in `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;`

Comment: You may have to use a custom converter: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5872855/497356

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the result you want is to use a custom `JsonConverter` that can limit the set of properties serialized.  Here is one that will only serialize the properties of a base type `T`:

```
public class BaseTypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                obj.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(prop.GetValue(value)));
            }
        }
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, mark the `Artist` property in your `Track` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute as shown below.  Then, only the `ArtistInfo` properties of the `Artist` will be serialized.

```
public class Track
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int? TrackNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(BaseTypeConverter<ArtistInfo>))]
    public ArtistInfo Artist { get; set; }
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/on9ng4)

Comment: Thanks a ton for dotnetfiddle link. I did not knew it exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Although Answer by Brian Rogers has been appropriate one. But if you need a quick solution than [JsonIgnore] property would come handy.

```
public class Artist : ArtistInfo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int UpdatedById { get; set; }
}
```

Check out [Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C3uqJA). I have updated Brian's code.